# populating select box from mysql using php in bonfire

Tags: php, codeigniter

Need help with populating data from mysql into a select box in bonfire.
I have 2 tables, currency and salary. The currency table is related to salary table (as foreign key). So im trying to load currency symbols in the salary form but somehow the code works on a mac but doesnt work on a linux machine.
The file: bonfire/modules/salary/views/content/create.php

```
<?php    
$options = array();
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT currency_symbol FROM currency");  
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
   foreach ($row as $key) {
        $options[] = $key;
   }
}
?>

<?php echo form_dropdown('salary_currency', $options, set_value('salary_currency', isset($salary['salary_currency']) ? $salary['salary_currency'] : ''), 'Currency')?>
```

And this is the code for the index.php in the td of html:
file path: bonfire/modules/salary/views/content/index.php

```
<?php    
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT currency_symbol FROM currency");  
$query_result = $query->result_array();
foreach ($query_result as $query_currency_id => $query_currency_symbol ) {
  if($query_currency_id == (integer)($record->salary_currency)){
    foreach ($query_currency_symbol as $salary_currency_id) {
      echo($salary_currency_id);
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: What exactly is happening when you say "it doesn't work" on linux? Are you getting errors?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but it seems to work on linux after I force refreshed the page.